# MySQL - Get a list of months on which events are taking place

Tags: mysql, date, select

I am working on a PHP application that displays events. It generates a select box that allows visitors to choose a month for which events should be displayed.

My problem is in regard to the select box, which should display not only months on which an event starts or ends, but also months during which an event is still taking place (even if it started months before and ends months later).

Here is what I've got at the moment, it's pretty basic and only returns months on which events start.

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(start,'%M %Y') as prettydate, 
  DATE_FORMAT(start,'%m%Y') as monthyear 
FROM 
  `events` 
WHERE 
  start >= NOW() 
ORDER BY 
  start ASC;
```

How can I also get February & July but also March, April, May & June 2014 in the result if the only event I've got in 2014 starts in February and finishes in July for example?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't have any events that span more than 1 year, and using the following start/end dates:

```
('2012-01-01','2012-01-31'),
('2012-03-01','2012-03-31'),
('2012-05-01','2012-06-01'),
('2012-07-01','2012-07-31'),
('2012-09-01','2012-10-31'),
('2012-11-01','2012-11-30');
```

this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(e.start + INTERVAL ids.id MONTH,'%M %Y') as prettydate, 
  DATE_FORMAT(e.start + INTERVAL ids.id MONTH,'%m%Y') as monthyear 
FROM 
(
  SELECT 0 AS id
  UNION SELECT 1
  UNION SELECT 2
  UNION SELECT 3
  UNION SELECT 4
  UNION SELECT 5
  UNION SELECT 6
  UNION SELECT 7
  UNION SELECT 8
  UNION SELECT 9
  UNION SELECT 10
  UNION SELECT 11
) ids,
  events e
WHERE
  EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM e.start + INTERVAL ids.id MONTH) <=
  EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM e.end)
ORDER BY 
  e.start + INTERVAL ids.id MONTH
```

will return:

```
prettydate      monthyear
January 2012    012012
March 2012      032012
May 2012        052012
June 2012       062012
July 2012       072012
September 2012  092012
October 2012    102012
November 2012   112012
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12b08/3 for a working example.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed! I assume if my table has events that last more than a year I just need to add more UNION SELECT x, incrementing x?

Comment: I worked a bit on the code you sent me and managed to plan for events that span more than 1 year... http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e55b1/11

Answer (score 0):

Select start and finish date for each event. Once you have finish date you can calculate which months are in between of event beginning and ending.

Try using http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

With that or your own formatting you can check if Starting date month and year are same as finish month and year. If they are not, simply fill out the list with, let's say some predefined array of months.

```
$months = array(1 => "Jan", 2 => "Feb", ... , 12 => "Dec");
```

then you can do something like
From there you can calculate the number of months in between and simply iterate through the $months array.

Comment: Thanks for your help inzenir. I thought about it, and it does work with my example above, however I've got many more events in the database, and if one of them takes place from Oct to Dec 2012 and the other one from March to July 2013, I would like Jan & Feb 2013 not to appear in my select box.

Comment: Try not going from first event start to last event finish, but do it for each event. Make a class that will return an array of years and months. After that create another array where you'll filter out the months you don't need in your display.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that would work! I wanted to use - but couldn't see - a MySQL solution (I am used to pretty basic requests), however PHP might be the easiest way to do it. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, do it with PHP, as it's usually easier to do something a bit more complex than with pure MySQL.